# Should "operator !=" always be implemented via "operator ==" in C++?

Tags: c++, comparison, operators, operator-overloading

I currently review an old C++ codebase and see a lot of code going like this:

```
bool SomeClass::operator==( const SomeClass& other ) const
{
   return member1 == other.member1 && member2 == other.member2;
}

bool SomeClass::operator!=( const SomeClass& other ) const
{
   return member1 != other.member1 || member2 != other.member2;
}
```

clearly comparison logic is duplicated and the code above will likely have to be changed in two places instead of in one.

AFAIK the typical way to implement `operator!=` is like this:

```
bool SomeClass::operator!=( const SomeClass& other ) const
{
    return !( *this == other );
}
```

In the latter case whatever logic change occurs in `operator==` it will automatically reflected in `operator!=` since it just calls `operator==` and performs negation.

Is there any resonable case where `operator!=` should be implemented in any other way except just reusing `operator==` in C++ code?

Comment: Similarly, one should try to  implement `>, >=, <=, <` operators  in least redundant way.

Comment: Rules should not be absolute. All rules hold in general. But I am sure there will always be specific instances where they don't. But coming up with one (unless you happened to do it yesterday) will be in general imposable (because they are exceptions to the rule). Its like asking are all swans white. Yes all swans are white (until the 1500 when black swans were discovered in Australia). Ceaser: "rara avis in terris nigroque simillima cygno"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases the semantics of `a!=b` should be equal to `!(a==b)`.

The same is true for about all the other operators: `a<b` should be equal to `!(a=>b)` and to `!(a==b || a>b)` and to `a<=b && !(a==b)` and so on and so forth.

To this purpose [boost.operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) offers some awesome tools to automatically generate operators in function of the others.

---

However when you give some particular semantics to your operators (ie: you don't use `==` to check whether two items are the same, but to do some fancy stuff like STL does with `>>` and `<<`) you could want to give them different implementations.

This practice, in general, is not suggested, although even STL and many boost libraries do that.

---

**EDIT** - A little addition:

what I said so far concerns only the semantics of operators. If you decide that the semantics of your `a!=b` should be `!(a==b)` you've got two ways to implement it:

- by calling the other operator, which is what happens if you use boost.operators:
  `bool operator!=(a,b) { return !(a==b); }`
- implementing both of them from scratch.

The first method is usually easier to implement and safer. The most common thing which could justify the second option are optimizations, although it's probably not worth it: modern compilers won't add any overhead in most cases (if you look to boost.operators source code you'll see many comments about how they rely on [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to add no overhead, or how their code change if compiler doesn't provide NRVO).

Whatever option you choose, anyway, it should make no difference to your application logic, since what matters is the semantics (ie: how your operators behaves, what they return for any possible input).

Comment: +1 for Boost.Operators, it's amazing how that tiny library makes implementing operators so much trivial. Not only you get rid of dependencies, but you also get rid of the glaring mistakes (switching arguments when implementing `<=` in term of `<` for example).

Answer (score 5):

IMHO it's both reasonable and robust to implement != in terms of ==. (or the other way around)

Comment: -1 for wrong suggestion.. how can you implement `==` in terms of `!=`?

Comment: @Nawaz: `a==b iff !(a!=b)`. That is by definition.

Answer (score 3):

semantically yes (meaning that == should be the logical complement of !=), but practically (coding) you do not have to.

Comment: I would say semantically you don't *need* to, but practically you *should*.

Comment: I meant == should be the semantic complement of !=, but practically (in programming) you do not have to use it to imply negation.

Comment: You were not wrong or anything :). Its just different way of seeing things. When you said 'practically' you were concerned with rules of C++, when I said 'practically', I was concerned with modular code that is easy to maintain. Don't read too much into my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any resonable case where `operator!=` should be implemented in any other way except just reusing `operator==` in C++ code?

I don’t think so. But the same holds for other code as well, e.g. postfix `++` should *always* be implemented in terms of prefix `++` (except of course for native types where the optimizer can generate more efficient code, but I believe even then the argument holds) and `operator +` should *almost always* be implemented in terms of `operator +=` (the exception is when you’re working with proxy objects to delay execution).

This is why `std::relops` exists.